# SQL: LEFT JOIN > If the ON condition fails are the conditions in the WHERE statement disregarded?

Tags: sql, join

If you use a LEFT JOIN and also have a WHERE clause, are all the conditions in the WHERE clause being disregarded if the table that you tried to join does not exist?

In other words, do I have to specifically compare against the id from the LEFT JOIN?

```
SELECT distinct(watchedItems.id) 
FROM globalItems, watchedItems 
  LEFT JOIN bidGroups ON bidGroups.bidGroupID = watchedItems.bidGroupID

WHERE    
  watchedItems.aid = globalItems.aid 
  AND watchedItems.processRunning = 0
  (watchedItems.bidGroupID IS NULL 
  OR (watchedItems.bidGroupID IS NOT NULL AND bidGroups.bidGroupQty > 0))
```

Could I write instead of the entire last bit just

```
AND bidGroups.bidGroupQty > 0
```

and it will not be tested because bidGroups does not exist if the LEFT JOIN fails? I know that without the LEFT JOIN it will definitely test against it all the time, which means if this test fails, the entire statement is not executed. But I want it to be executed in any case (with and without bidGroups.)

Comment: You need to stop using the implicit syntax, it is poor programming practice that was replaced almost 20 years ago. Combining implicit and explicit syntax as you have done here can also result in incorrect results on some databases. Implicit syntax is harder to maintain (especially when you want to add left joins or if you don't know if the cross join was intended or accidental) and more likely to contain errors that affect the resutls set such as accidental cross joins.

Comment: Thanks for the advice HLGEM. I never knew that there is a difference between the two. For anyone else reading this, there is a link with useful info here: http://www.cactusjuice.com/blogs/archive/2006/12/12/SQL-Server-JOIN-Syntax-Explicit-vs-Implicit.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>If the table doesn't exist your statement won't parse and will result in a SQL exception.</strike>

**EDIT**

I'd write your query this way, for readability:

```
SELECT distinct(watchedItems.id)
FROM globalItems INNER JOIN
     watchedItems ON globalItems.aid = watchedItems.aid LEFT JOIN
     bidGroups ON bidGroups.bidGroupID = watchedItems.bidGroupID
WHERE
    watchedItems.processRunning = 0
AND (watchedItems.bidGroupID IS NULL
     OR (watchedItems.bidGroupID IS NOT NULL
     AND bidGroups.bidGroupQty > 0)
);
```

The answer to whether you need to check `watchedItems.bigGroupID IS NOT NULL` is **no**, you do not have to as the join condition already covers that.

Comment: Thanks, Yuck, I just realized, I made a mistake in the phrasing of my question. I meant, if a table is empty or the condition in LEFT  JOIN cannot be met.

Answer (score 2):

First, I wouldn't mix syntax; the `,` and `JOIN` mix is a head ache :)  Then move the conditions into the LEFT JOIN instead of the WHERE clause?

```
SELECT
  distinct(watchedItems.id) 
FROM
  globalItems
INNER JOIN
  watchedItems 
    ON watchedItems.aid = globalItems.aid
LEFT JOIN
  bidGroups
    ON  bidGroups.bidGroupID = watchedItems.bidGroupID
    AND bidGroups.bidGroupQty > 0
WHERE    
  watchedItems.processRunning = 0
```

Comment: This answer gives a subtly different result than the OP's query.  When bidGroupQty>0 was in the WHERE clause, items with bidGroupQty<=0 would not be returned.  By moving bidGroupQty>0 to the ON clause of the LEFT JOIN, items with bidGroupQty<=0 will not be joined but *will* be returned from the main query.

Answer (score 1):

If left join fails, columns from the missing row all will have value of null, so your test `bidGroups.bidGroupQty` will always fail.  If you want the test to succeed on missing row from left join, the longer logic you have is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The conditions in the `where` clause are always enforced as written, so you either need to added the null-test logic or move the filter conditions for the outer join to a sub-query.  Personally, I'd rewrite your query like so:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT (watcheditems.id)
  FROM              globalitems
         INNER JOIN watcheditems
                 ON watcheditems.aid = globalitems.aid
         LEFT JOIN  (SELECT   bidgroupid
                       FROM   bidgroups
                      WHERE   bidgroups.bidgroupqty > 0) bg
                 ON bg.bidgroupid = watcheditems.bidgroupid
 WHERE   watcheditems.processrunning = 0
```

The other change I made was to move your inner join into the `from` clause. Generally, it's a better practice to use the SQL99 standard of putting the joins in the `from` clause, but whichever method you choose to use, you should be consistent.  Putting joins in both the `where` clause and the `from` clause is just going to lead to confusion.